# Two subscriptions chained to refactor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to refactor the code below with two subscriptions (one in the method and one in the service) and I don't find a way to do it.

I am using [akita](https://netbasal.gitbook.io/akita/) to handle my states. So it is recommended to use subscriptions in services as mentioned in the [documentation](https://netbasal.gitbook.io/akita/core-concepts/the-service).

This code is to handle the case of a denormalization: my language field of the User collection in the Service collection with MongoDB.

Here is the models I use:

**user model**

```
export interface UserInfo {
  [...]
  services: ID[];
}

export interface User {
  _id: ID;
  [...]
  userInfo: Partial<UserInfo>;
}
```

**service model**

```
export interface ServiceInfo {
  [...]
  userFamilyName: string;
  userGivenName: string;
  userLanguages: Language[];
}

export interface Service {
  _id: ID;
  [...]
  serviceInfo: Partial<ServiceInfo>;
}
```

**In my method**

```
private addLanguage(languageForm: FormGroup) {

  [...]

  this.usersService.addLanguage(user).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  ).subscribe(
    (entity: User) => {
      if (entity.userInfo.services) {
        entity.userInfo.services.forEach(serviceId => {
          const service = createService({
            _id: serviceId,
            serviceInfo: {
              userLanguages: [language]
            }
          });

          this.servicesService.addLanguage(service); <--- have also a subscribe in its method
        })
      }

      languageForm.reset();
      this.onNavigateBack();
    }
  );
}
```

**In the service**

```
addLanguage(service: Service) {
  const url = `${this.servicesUrl}/${service._id}/languages`;
  const accessToken = this.authQuery.getSnapshot().accessToken;
  this.http.post<Service>(url, service, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': accessToken
    })
  }).subscribe(
    (entity: Service) => {
      if (this.servicesQuery.hasEntity(service._id)) {
        this.servicesStore.update(service._id, entity);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
this.usersService.addLanguage(user).pipe(
  filter((entity: User) => entity.userInfo.services !== undefined),
  switchMap((entity: User) => {
    entity.userInfo.services.forEach(serviceId => {
      const service = createService({
        _id: serviceId,
        serviceInfo: {
          userLanguages: [language]
        }
      });

      return this.servicesService.addLanguage(service);
    })
  }
);
```

But I am stuck because of the `entity.userInfo.services.forEach`.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you care about `if (entity.userInfo.services)` equals to false? no right?

Comment: Also, if your service's `addLanguage` is returning a `Service` type, why is it that at component it is retrieving as `User` type?

Comment: I am using this code to handle a denormalization of my language field (User collection in Service collection in MongoDB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are seeing a subscribe inside your service, probably there is something wrong with the code. You will need to use `.tap()` to do some side effect manipulation. Never subscribe in a service, let the component handles the subscription.

In service:

```
addLanguage(service: Service) {
    const url = `${this.servicesUrl}/${service._id}/languages`;
    const accessToken = this.authQuery.getSnapshot().accessToken;
    this.http.post<Service>(url, service, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': accessToken
        })
    })
        .pipe(
            tap((entity: Service) => {
                if (this.servicesQuery.hasEntity(service._id)) {
                    this.servicesStore.update(service._id, entity);
                }
            })
        );
}
```

In your component though, you can easily achieve this using a `filter()` and a `switchMap()` from `rxjs`. The trick for the `forEach`, is that you use `.map()` from the native Javascript array function. After you have created such array of Observables, you can use `forkJoin()` to combine them and have them fired in parallel:

In component:

```
private addLanguage(languageForm: FormGroup) {
    this.usersService.addLanguage(user).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
        //filter away the conditions  
        filter((entity: User) => entity.userInfo.services),
        switchMap((entity: User) => {
            //use .map() to create an array of services.
            let serviceObs$ = entity.UserInfo.services.map(serviceId =>
                this.servicesService.addLanguage(createService({
                    _id: serviceId,
                    serviceInfo: {
                        userLanguages: [language]
                    }
                })));
            //use forkJoin to combine all of them
            return forkJoin(serviceObs$);
        })
    ).subscribe(() => {
            languageForm.reset();
            this.onNavigateBack();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Actually `entity.UserInfo.services` is already an array. With you solution I have this error message : Argument of type 'Service[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Service'. I edited my post to provide more information.

Comment: @jodandelion ah my mistake. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! I didn't know about the forkJoin operator. Now, I know :)

Comment: I have one more question. Is that normal the subscribe is not reached when I don't have services in my users? (services in user mode is not defined or empty). The languageForm.reset(); this.onNavigateBack(); are not fired in this case. I updated my initial post to show you my actual version.

Comment: @jodandelion yes. `forkJoin()` will wait for all Observables to be completed before it emits. if you need, you can try `combineLatest()`